Is it possible to call psql with an password encrypted in PowerShell?
Is it possible to call psql with passwords encrypted in Powershell?
There are many documents that describe hiding passwords with Get-Credential, ConvertFrom-SecureString and ConvertTo-SecureString.
Even though that's not a perfect solution, I'd like to try that for on PostgreSQL passwords in a PowerShell script.
But, psql is not accepting the password passed by ConvertTo-SecureString.
Is there a way to do it?

What about using.pgpass ?

We are using it (pgpass) at the moment. But, we are trying hide/ mask the passwords at least at the first sight.

The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication. in your case this probably that you should setup and run the script under the account that Connecting through Windows Authentication

Actually, below commands worked after upgrading to PowerShell 7.
It returned the original password in plain text.
ConvertTo-SecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText 

